# В какой момент необходимо нажимать кнопку "Готово"?

Tags: поддержка

В процессе проверки первых сообщений новых участников нередко возникает необходимость отредактировать сообщение или отметить его "тревогой". Так как мой уровень репутации не позволяет завершить эти действия без дополнительной проверки более опытными членами сообщества, проверяемое сообщение переходит в стадию ожидания одобрения правок/тревоги, но у меня становится активной кнопка "Готово", которую я теперь, согласно изложенным на странице проверки правилам, формально имею право нажать.
Но возникает вопрос: когда я должен это сделать? Сразу же после отправки моего предложения по правке вопроса (или отметки вопроса "тревогой") или только после подтверждения моей правки/тревоги?
Есть ли какие-то рекомендадции (или просто общая практика) на этот счет?